# Expected SET in UPDATE statement H2 DB error code: 42001

Tags: sql, h2, sonarqube

I'm currenlty trying to execute the following statement I found on the internet to change a snapshot from Sonar.

```
UPDATE snapshots as old_snap, 
       snapshots as new_snap 
SET old_snap.islast = 0 
where old_snap.islast=1 
and new_snap.created_at > old_snap.created_at 
and new_snap.project_id = old_snap.project_id 
and new_snap.islast=1;
```

But when executing the statement it says it expects a SET.

> Error: Syntax error in SQL statement "UPDATE SNAPSHOTS AS
>   OLD_SNAP,[*]NEW_SNAP  SET OLD_SNAP.ISLAST = 0 WHERE OLD_SNAP.ISLAST=1
>   AND NEW_SNAP.CREATED_AT > OLD_SNAP.CREATED_AT AND NEW_SNAP.PROJECT_ID
>   = OLD_SNAP.PROJECT_ID AND NEW_SNAP.ISLAST=1 "; expected "SET"; SQL statement: UPDATE snapshots as old_snap,new_snap  SET old_snap.islast
>   = 0 where old_snap.islast=1 and new_snap.created_at > old_snap.created_at and new_snap.project_id = old_snap.project_id and
>   new_snap.islast=1 [42001-178] SQLState:  42001 ErrorCode: 42001

Anyone who can fix this statement?

Comment: Your trying to update only `old_snap table`. Let the other table be in a sub-query.

Comment: You can't specifiy two tables in the `UPDATE` clause: http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#update

Comment: Can you maybe help changing the statement? I don't really know what to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE statement changes rows in a table.

The typical UPDATE statement specifies the following information:

The `table_name` to be changed table name:

A `WHERE` clause that filters the to be changed rows

A list of column names, along with their new values, specified using the `SET` clause

You can change one or more rows using the same `UPDATE` statement.

If more than one row is specified, the same change will be implemented for all of those rows.

`Update` Synthax:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET (column_name = value)
WHERE statement

UPDATE snapshots as old_snap
SET old_snap.islast = 0
WHERE old_snap.islast=1 
and (select new_snap.created_at 
     from snapshots new_snap
     where new_snap.project_id = old_snap.project_id 
     and new_snap.islast=1
     ) > old_snap.created_at;
```